# J2SE Client Server App: Client calls RMI method. Server handles RMI method and returns, but Client never receives it. Any ideas?

Tags: client, rmi, java

J2SE Client Server App:  Client calls RMI message.  Server handles RMI method and returns, but Client never receives it.

Any ideas how this could happen?  Our attempted solution is to set client read timeouts and come up with a framework for resending requests or otherwise handling those failures gracefully.

But really, I'd like to know any root causes for how this might happen rather than addressing the symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have firewalls between client and server? Rmi lookup first the registry and it's not predictable which ports are used for communication.
Checkout networking tools like http://www.wireshark.org/ to track down the problem.